# What happens to an electron in vacuum?

Tags: electrons, vacuum

What happens to a free electron in vacuum? Does it accelerate? Does it keep absorbing energy from vacuum fluctuations? Or does it lose all its energy and ceases to be an electron? Please avoid technical terms, as I am relatively new to this field. Thank you!!

Comment: If you are new to this field, not wanting to sound like an ass, but this may be just a bit over your level of knowledge should be able to grasp and understand. We need to use technical terms to accurately answer questions, and such complex matters require even more complex terms and previous knowledge. Physics is like any other skill, it takes time to hone and perfect and learn.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Ok, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All systems described by [relativistic four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) , i.e. have a fixed invariant mass, and an electron as all elementary particles has a fixed invariant mass, by energy momentum conservation retain their energy and momentum, until they interact. So the electron if it is at rest, remains at rest, if in motion keeps its momentum.

If you are thinking the theoretical [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) it is used in describing interactions to avoid infinities in calculations. There are no interactions for a free electron in vacuum.

Comment: Then won't we be able to determine exactly its position and momentum, if it is at rest?

Comment: There is the Heisenberg uncertainty which limits the "exact'" . The mathematics for free electrons use wave packets.http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html

Comment: Well... I know it's embarrassing, but can it get simpler?

Comment: quantum mechanics cannot get simpler, it needs mathematics to really understand physics observations at the microcosm of particles, and not only

Comment: if by simpler you mean the concept of wave paket here it comes:  One cannot represent a free particle by a single frequency, because then it would have a uniform probability to exist anywhere.When close by frequencies are summed in a wavepacket the packet is localzed with the uncertainty of its width (which expressed as momentum, obeys the heisenberg uncertainty). The energy  is equal to the hν, and the momentum can be calculated simply from that to give the ΔpΔx envelope of the probable localization